# React Router Dom conditionally rendering an element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am setting up a new project and using the latest version of `react-router-dom`. Their documentation suggests using `createBrowserRouter` which I am working on implementing.

What I want to achieve is rendering a different header depending on the path params.

Currently I am using an optional path param:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/:appTypeId?',
    element: <ReferralDetails status="new" />,
  },
])
```

Now, if an `appTypeId` is provided I want to render my `<Header />` component above my `<ReferralDetails />` component.

Something like:

```
<>
  <Header />
  <ReferralDetails />
</>
```

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a route component that can read the optional `appTypeId` path parameter and conditionally render `Header`.

Example:

```
const Referrals = (props) => {
  const { appTypeId } = useParams();

  return (
    <>
      {appTypeId && <Header />}
      <ReferralDetails {...props} />
    </>
  );
};
```

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/:appTypeId?',
    element: <Referrals status="new" />,
  },
]);
```

To be a bit more flexible you may consider a layout route component.

Example:

```
import { Outlet, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const AppLayout = (props) => {
  const { appTypeId } = useParams();

  return (
    <>
      {appTypeId && <Header />}
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};
```

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/:appTypeId?',
    element: <AppLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <ReferralDetails status="new" />,
      },
      ... other routes with conditional header
    ],
  },
]);
```